# Achieve static files in CakePHP regardless of the URL

Tags: cakephp, path

I'm developing a site with CakePHP but I have a very basic doubt:

When I'm working on local, I use a virtual Host, then `/` means really the root of my project, then I can define all my links to static content like `/static/content.css` (i.e.). However, when I test the website I need to create a `beta` subdirectory, then the links should be changed to `/beta/static/content.css`.

Using relative paths like `static/content.css` isn't a solution because this will only work in the main page, whereas on other controllers and actions the files are unreachable because the system look for them in `controller/action/static/content.css`.

My first solution is creating a global constant that I must redefine in every place I test my page (my local server, my remote server, the client remote server...) but I hope that CakePHP provides a way to solve this problem in a more elegant way.

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: you might like to consider using [Themes](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1093/Themes), if you are trying to develop a `beta` site on top of an existing one; just set the theme for admins, for instance. Or use a separate install of cake. Depends what you are attempting really

Comment: Thanks, I think what you say is useful to update a portal or something like that, but it's not my case: I can't create subdomains, I can't use the main domain with testing stuff, but the project is new. I think the intuitive solution is a subfolder, and I thank CakePHP has to provide a less traumatic way to do this without  redefining constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you should not be using static urls for anything, but instead be doing things like `echo $this->Html->css('your_file');` which would point to `/webroot/css/your_file.css`

Comment: And with the HtmlHelper I shouldn't configure any kind of global constant? This is doing automatically?

Comment: If you needed to do something else I would have stated that in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, and I found an interesting variable: $this->webroot, useful if somebody wants to avoid the HtmlHelper for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty weird to me. Why not have a branch in your git/svn/whatever repo called "beta" and simply use: example.com (live site) and beta.example.com (beta site) for testing with separated folders, vhosts and databases. You said *testing*, so I would not try to use beta features on a live db.

Comment: The special branch in the repo isn't needed because it's a new project with two persons working on it (a main branch is enough). About db, i'm using a testing one. And about the subdomain (it will be a good solution) because the clients usually don't bring us a subdomain.